# Code is running before API call response in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Before my API response below code is getting running.
I want to get a response from the API call based on the API response I want to proceed further

```
 this._httpservice.getOrderList().subscribe((response: any) => {
  Object.entries(response.content).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    this.orderList.set(key, value as Array<String>);   //Set Value in Map
  });
}, error => {
  this.errorDetails = error;
});
```

//Based on the Map value I want to push  values in an array

```
this.orderList.get(this.orderName).map(value => {
  this.availableOrders.push(value);
});
```

Comment: Either you move your code inside the `subscribe` or you convert the observable (`getOrderList`) and await it instead of a subscription.

Comment: Additional information: the subscription is async and the code below is processed directly. this is way you need "special" strategies to handle your case.

Comment: I tried adding inside subscribe but it is not working as expected

Comment: What is your expectation? (i guess in this case more details needed)

Comment: Can you suggest me any example for await?

Comment: It depends on the rxjs version you are using, if you are using modern version: `const village = firstValueFrom(this.http.post<Village>('https://localhost:5000/village/create', village))`. In param for `firstValueFrom` is not the subscription, the observable it is. Please see: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, do not subscribe to something that is set via subscription, and do not subscribe within a subscribe. Both are strong indicators there's a better way.

In your case, it sounds like you want `availableOrders` to be updated as appropriate. Have you considered making `availableOrders` an observable?

For example:

```js
type OrderList = Record<string, Array[string]>;


const orderList: OrderList = {};

const orderList$ = this._httpservice.getOrderList().pipe(
  map(({content}) => Object.assign(this.orderList, content)),
  shareReplay(1) // not needed if you only have one downstream subscriber
);

const orderName$: Subject<string> = new Subject(); // no idea how you populate this in your app. Maybe FormControl.ValueChanges?

const availableOrders$ = this.orderName$.pipe(
  combineLatestWith(this.orderList$),
  map(([nm, orderList]) => orderList[nm])
);
```

No subscriptions you need to clean up. And then in your template you can replace `availableOrders` with `availableOrders$ | async`.